# Viewing PFUser's PFObjects - Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I have system set up where a `user` makes a post (`PFObject`) and is posted to a tableview controller with all of the other user(s) post that post to the tableview. I want to be able to grab the posts (`PFObjects`) of just ONE user and be able to display them in a seperate tableview so that the `user` can just see what they have posted.

This is how I post the PFObject:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
    [quoteNew setObject:user forKey:@"author"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self attributionTitle] text] forKey:@"title"];
    [quoteNew setObject:@"Story" forKey:@"cato"];

     PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    [quoteNew setACL:postACL];
```

This is how I retrieve into the table view:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"New";
       // self.className2 = @"Story";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"title";

        self.User = @"cato";
       // self.textKey2 = @"title";

        // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
         //self.imageKey = @"image";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
       // self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hi @user2977529 - You haven't upvoted a single answer to any of your questions, and you've only accepted one.  There are several correct answers to your questions.  While you are not obligated to do any of this, it does show a bit of gratitude towards people taking the time to help you.  Eventually, people will stop if they notice this trend.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice, thanks friend! @Logan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to overwrite the  queryForTable method to set the query parameters

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"name"];  //where you set the username to the specific user to get only this user's post. 
    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.

   if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}
```

check out https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS  under PFQueryTableViewController.